# Super CSV: Looking for integer equivalent to LMinMax

Tags: java, supercsv

With supercsv, I can apply minimum and maximum constraints to a long column using LMinMax(), but how can I do that with a column that maps to an integer? If I use LMinMax on a column that maps to an integer in my bean, when I try to read the file in I get a org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvReflectionException because it is looking for a setter that takes a long rather than an integer.

Comment: This might be a hack - but you can always add a setter wth `long` parameter and inside it, cast the parameter to `int` and call your normal `int` setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only cell processor combination that would work is something like

```
new LMinMax(0, 10, new FmtNumber("###", new ParseInt()))
```

which is horrible.

The issue is that Super CSV's `ReflectionUtils` only allows for exact matches on type (autoboxing is supported though). You could raise a feature request on Github to get this fixed.

You can work around this by using `CsvDozerBeanReader` (Dozer supports mapping from `Long` to `Integer` quite happily), or you could define your own custom cell processor as shown below.

```
public class IntMinMax extends LMinMax {

    public IntMinMax(int min, int max) {
        super(min, max);
    }

    @Override
    public Object execute(Object value, CsvContext context) {
        Long result = (Long) super.execute(value, context);
        return result.intValue();
    }

}
```

This should work, but note that it doesn't allow processors being chained after it (the call to `super.execute()` reuses the min/max validation, but also means you can't stop it passing the `Long` to the next processor, so I just disabled chaining).

Comment: Thanks very much. I'm using the custom cell processor you provided and it works well.